# Formatting multiselect lookup in XSLT

Tags: data-view-web-part, xslt, multi-select

I'm using [this](http://spxslt.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MultiSelectDisplay&referringTitle=Documentation) function to render items in a multi-select lookup field so that each one appears on a new line instead of AA;BB;CC;DD etc. This method uses the substring-before and substring-after functions on a loop to extract the semicolon-delimited values.

The trouble comes when there is an ampersand or other encoded character in the returned values. For example AA;B&C;DD is parsed as AA;B& amp;C;DD so the final result is

AA
B&amp
C

Is there a better way to extract the delimited values, telling xslt to separate on ';' but ignore '& amp;' ?

(I added the space in & amp; because the parser was outputting ampersands!!)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just need to add `disable-output-escaping="yes"` to your xsl:value-of statement you display the `&amp;` as a `&`.

Comment: Hey PirateEric, thanks for the reply. That was the first thing I tried, however I found that the rendering of the xsl:value-of occurs _after_ the substring-before and substring-after functions are called on the original, encoded string.